# log4j appender sometimes not invoked

Tags: java, log4j

i have four appender , sometimes work and sometimes  not invoked ?
this is the log4j.conf :

```
 # Trace appender
    log4j.appender.WsAppender=it.tracciaturaEventi.WsTraceAppender
    log4j.appender.DbAppenderOld=it.tracciaturaEventi.DbTraceAppenderOld
    log4j.appender.DBAppender=it.tracciaturaEventi.DBTraceAppender
    log4j.appender.JAppender=it.tracciaturaEventi.JAppender

    ### trace conf
    log4j.logger.it.a.b.TRACING=info, WsAppender, DbAppenderOld,DBAppender,JAppender
    log4j.additivity.it.a.b.TRACING=false
    log4j.logger.it.a.b.TRACING.c=info, WsAppender, JAppender
    log4j.additivity.it.a.b.TRACING.c=false
    log4j.logger.it.a.b.TRACING.d=info, DbAppenderOld, DBAppender
    log4j.additivity.it.a.b.TRACING.d=false
```

and this a class appender

```
 public class WsTraceAppender extends appenderSkeleton {
        @Override
        public void append(LoggingEvent ev) {
            TraceTO msg = msg(ev);
            if (msg == null) return;
            try {
                TraceWS.callWS(msg.properties);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new TracingRuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

in one day , sometimes work , perfectly and in a other day not invoked , and i don't have errors in log

sorry for my english